# unable to pass javascript object in jquery.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object stored in variable `dashboard_filter_value_attributes` which hold the tableau filter names which I am trying to send via post to my rails controller for further processing.

when i do `console.log(dashboard_filter_value_attributes)`, i see the below output on the console, i have expanded the 0th index key that why you see `__proto__: Object` in the below output

```
{}
0:
filter_name: "Filter One"
__proto__: Object
1: {filter_name: "Filter Two"}
2: {filter_name: "Filter Theree"}
3: {filter_name: "Filter Four"}
4: {filter_name: "Filter Five"}
5: {filter_name: "Filter Six"}
6: {filter_name: "Filter Seven"}
7: {filter_name: "Filter Eight"}
8: {filter_name: "Filter Nine"}
9: {filter_name: "Filter Ten"}
__proto__: Object
```

I have defined  `let dashboard_filter_value_attributes = {};`

but I am unable to send the object via post. The object is not getting passed and is ingnored during the `jQuery.post` execution, i also do not see any error on the console.

Here is my `jQuery.post` call

```
let activeSheet = tableauViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
let viewName = 'my custom view';
let counter = 0;
let dashboard_filter_value_attributes = {};


activeSheet.getWorksheets().forEach(function(worksheet) {
  if (worksheet.getName() == "Filter") {
    worksheet.getFiltersAsync().then(function(filterParameterList) {
      filterParameterList.forEach(function(fp) {
        const name = filter ? fp.getFieldName() : fp.getName();
        dashboard_filter_value_attributes[counter] = {
          filter_name: name,
        };
        counter =  counter + 1;
      }
    });
  });
});

jQuery.post($('#new_dashboard_filter').attr('action'), {
  dashboard_filter: {
    name:viewName,
    dashboard_filter_values: dashboard_filter_value_attributes
  }
});
```

I have also tried to use JSON.strigify but even then I am not able to post the object to my rails controller.

When i use `console.log(JSON.strigify(dashboard_filter_value_attributes));` i see `[]`

Any help in this would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: it seens your dashboard_filter_value_attributes is an empty array

Comment: @ArielBatista, i have posted what i see on console when i print `dashboard_filter_value_attributes `

Comment: _"Any help in this..."_ - For this you will have to add a [mcve]. Otherwise we can only guess (and one of mine would be that your "array" looks fishy)

Comment: @Andreas, sure i will try to do that, the object `dashboard_filter_value_attributes` hold array of other objects and in the question i have tried to expand one of the keys, thats why you see  `__proto__: Object`

Comment: _"When i use console.log(JSON.strigify(dashboard_filter_value_attributes)); i see []"_ - Which would not be possible if you didn't change the content of `dashboard_filter_value_attributes` because you're assigning it an empty object and not an array -> [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas, I have updated the question with how i am constructing the `dashboard_filter_value_attributes` params.

Comment: where are you define the `dashboard_filter_value_attributes`, can you update the code?

Comment: And with that we're back at the famous -> [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: ah, @Andreas, thanks for pointing, my bad, should have realised it, but many thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be in the method used to define your Array/Object

> I have defined `let dashboard_filter_value_attributes = {};`

This defines an empty Object, but then you have filled it with items with numeric keys (0-9), which is what an Array is typically used for. Of course Arrays are Objects in JavaScript but Objects typically have named keys (filter_name_1 or something).

The short form to define an Array in JavaScript is `[]`, not `{}`